# Proving $N(A ∪ B) = N(A) + N(B) − N(A ∩ B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets. N(A) is the number of elements in the set A. I need to prove that:

$$N(A ∪ B) = N(A) + N(B) − N(A ∩ B)$$

Using the following representation of A ∪ B as a union of disjoint sets:

$$A \cup B = \big(A − (A \cap B)\big) \cup B$$

I'm not sure where I would start with this... any help is appreciated!

Comment: You were missing a required pair of parentheses in the second displayed line; I’ve added them.

Comment: @Newb Did you even read the post? =)

Answer (score 0):

HINTS: I don’t want to say very much, since this is an extremely straightforward problem, but these two questions might get you thinking in the right direction:

- If the finite sets $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, what is $N(X\cup Y)$ in terms of $N(X)$ and $N(Y)$?
- If $X$ is finite, and $Y\subseteq X$, what is $N(X\setminus Y)$ in terms of $N(X)$ and $N(Y)$?

Comment: I've never studied sets in my life and need to learn them now. I know the logical solution to this. Since obviously A union B counts the intersection of A and B twice. However, I am not sure how to use this fact: A∪B=(A−(A∩B))∪B

Comment: @Eric: Forget proving anything for a moment; can you simply answer the two questions that I asked?

Comment: If they are disjoint N(X)+N(Y) and N(X\Y) is N(X)-N(Y)?

Comment: @Eric: Yes, that’s exactly right. And I’m fairly sure that you’re not expected to prove those two facts, unless your course has dealt pretty rigorously with the notion of finite cardinalities. Can you see how to use those facts to calculate $N(A\setminus(A\cap B)$ and then the desired result?

Comment: So from (A−(A∩B))∪B; is it not just (A−(A∩B))+B which is A + B - (A∩B) ?

Comment: @Eric: Well, you need some $N$’s in there, but yes, that’s the idea.

Comment: Right, that's the problem that I have, I have no knowledge of how to properly lay out this solution and when to introduce N. Would I just define that A∪B is a disjoint union in written words? And define N(A) as the number of elements in A in words?

Comment: @Eric: $A$ is a set of objects; $N(A)$ is the number of objects in that set. You use $A$ when you want to talk about the set; you use $N(A)$ when you want to talk about the number of objects in that set. Thus, it makes no sense to write $A+B$: $A$ and $B$ are sets, and addition is not an operation on sets. It does make sense, however, to write $N(A)+N(B)$: $N(A)$ and $N(B)$ are integers, and we do have an operation of addition on the integers. // $A\cup B$ is **not** necessarily a disjoint union, but $\big(A\setminus(A\cap B)\big)\cup B$ is one; why?

Comment: A ∪ B can contain elements of both sets whereas (A∖(A∩B))∪B is a union of A and B without the intersection of the two sets. Would that be correct to say?

Comment: @Eric: You may have the right idea in mind, but what you’ve said isn’t right. $A\cap B$ may be non-empty, so $A$ and $B$ need not be disjoint. However, $A\setminus(A\cap B)$ and $B$ are disjoint: if $x\in A\setminus(A\cap B)$, then $x\in A$ and $x\notin A\cap B$. Since $x\notin A\cap B$, either $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$ (or both), but we know that $x\in A$, so $x\notin B$. Thus, $x\in A\setminus(A\cap B)$ implies that $x\notin B$, and it follows that $A\setminus(A\cap B)$ and $B$ are disjoint, and hence that ...

Comment: ... $$N\big(\big(A\setminus(A\cap B)\big)\cup B\big)=N\big(A\setminus(A\cap B)\big)+N(B)\;.$$